# Unit test with http as dependency for wrapper function

Tags: unit-testing, go, dependency-injection

I’ve the following function which after help of @poy I was able to create mock for it in order to unit test it.

The issue now that I’ve wrapper function which needs also to be tested

This is the **original** function which have working test

```
func httpReq(cc []string, method string, url string) ([]byte, error) {
    httpClient := http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "failed to execute http request")
    }
    //Here we are passing user and password
    req.SetBasicAuth(cc[1], cc[2])
    res, err := httpClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.error(err)
    }
    val, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.error(err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    return val, nil
}
```

This is the test which works as expected, this test use 
https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/ in order to mock http requests.

```
func Test_httpReq(t *testing.T){

  expectedValue = "some-value"
  server := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

    u,p,ok := r.BasicAuth()
    if !ok || u != "fakeuser" || p != "fakepassword" {
      t.Fatal("wrong auth")
    }
    w.Write([]byte(expectedValue))
  })

  val, err := httpReq(
   []string{"fakeuser", "fakepassword"}, 
   http.MethodPost, 
   server.URL,
  )

  if err != nil{
    t.Fatal(err)
  }

  if val != expectedValue {
    t.Fatalf("expected %q to equal %q", val, expectedValue)
  }
```

Now the issue is that I’ve another function **which call to the above function** which needs to be tested also.

**This is the function which use httpReq and I need to create test also for it**

```
func (c *Service) invoke(Connection Connection, args []string) {
    service, err := c.getService(Connection, args)

    serviceC, err := c.getServiceK(service, []string{"url", “user”, “id”})
    c := strings.Fields(serviceC)
        //—————Here we are using the http function again 
    val, err := httpReq(c[1], c[1],”post”, c[0])
    if err != nil {
        fmt.println(err)
    }
    fmt.Print(string(val))
}
```

Now when I use the test for it I got error inside the **http request method** since here I cannot mock the http.

Is there any `technique` In `Golang` Which can help which this kind of scenario?
 I've search about it, something like dependency injection and found that maybe *interface could help*, but since this is http I'm not sure how to do it.

Any example with this context will be very helpful to me.

Comment: First, the code failed to compile. Second, the test will be always failed because the given password is different with the expected password. Third, the code will be panic as index out of range because of this code `req.SetBasicAuth(cc[1], cc[2])`. For the unit test for the wrapper, the key thing is to mock the getServiceK to return the URL and user/password you want and then you can use the same method with the `Test_httpReq` to test it.

Comment: @thanhpham - thanks for the answer, 1. the password issue was fixed 2. assume that I mock the `getServiceK` to return URL how this will work in the tests? 3. which URL I should use in test (just for testing) ? example in highlevel of what you suggest will be very helpful to me :) thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @shopia T, could u please post the full working code? Need to see how you implement Connection, getService and getServiceK. If u can give me a working code, I will able to help to give a working test :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service object can have an interface like this

```
type Service struct {
    serviceK typeK
    serviceHttp serviceHttp // of type interface hence can be mocked
}
```

Normal application code can init services with actual objects. Tests will have mocks objects

```
type Req struct {
}

type Resp struct {
}

type ServiceHttp interface{
    HttpReq(params Req)(Resp, error)
}

type Implementation struct {
}

func (i *Implementation)HttpReq(params Req)(Resp, error){
   // buid http request
}

func (c *Service) invoke(Connection Connection, args []string) {

    service, err := c.getService(Connection, args)

    serviceC, err := c.getServiceK(service, []string{"url", “user”, “id”})
    c := strings.Fields(serviceC)

    serviceImp := c.GetServiceImp()

    // init params with the required fields
    val, err := c.HttpReq(params)
    if err != nil {
      fmt.println(err)
    }
    fmt.Print(string(val))

}
```

when you are running tests, you can initialise the service object with mock Implementation that returns a dummy response.

```
type MockImplementation struct {
}

func (i *MockImplementation)HttpReq(Resp, error){
    // return mock response
}

func TestMain(){
  services := {
     serviceHttp:MockImplementation{},
     serviceK: typeK{}, // initialise this
  }
}
```

This is one of way testing it. Other way could be I guess where httpReq return http.ResponseWriter and you can use httptest.ResponseRecorder to test it.