# Test wrap function with dependency injection

Tags: go, dependency-injection

I have this function which I need to mock in test,
I was able to mock it as expected with http mock package , but now I’ve function that are calling
To the `HttpReq` method and here I cannot use http mock package
I read about dependency injection and tried something but I wasn’t able to fully do it,

This is the function

```
type params struct {
    cs     string
    ci     string
    method string
    url    string
}

// I added this struct but not sure if it's needed ... probably for test purpose but not sure how to use it.

type Impl struct {
 client *http.Client
}

func (i *Impl) HttpReq(p *params) ([]byte, error) {
    httpClient := i.client
    req, err := http.NewRequest(p.method, p.url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Sprintf(err)
    }
    req.SetBasicAuth(p.cs, p.ci)
    res, err := httpClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Sprintf(err)
    }
    t, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Sprintf(err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    return t, nil
}
```

This is what I tried

I’ve created interface

```
type Req interface {
    HttpReq(params) ([]byte, error)
}
```

Now I’ve created a struct which contain the interface

```
type Service struct {
    req Req
}
```

This is the function which I need to tests

```
func (c *Service) execute(cli Connection , args []string) (error, []byte) {
    sk, err := c.doSomthing(cli, args)

    sc, err := c.doSometing2(serviceK, []string{"url", "cl", "ct"})

    cc := strings.Fields(serviceCredentials)

    // ----------Here is what I need to mock ----------
    t, err := c.req.HttpReq(params{cs: cc[1],
        ci:     cc[2],
        method: http.MethodPost,
        url:    cc[0],})
    return err, t
}
```

Any idea how I can run test for this function ??? Im struggling with it a lot.

Comment: Aside: Don't create a new client for each request: "The Client's Transport typically has internal state (cached TCP connections), so Clients should be reused instead of created as needed." https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client

Comment: @Peter - you suggest to put is as global ?

Comment: I suggest you inject the client. Then you can easily continue using a server from the httptest package.

Comment: @Peter - but if I inject it the caller will create it again and again , isnt it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Independent of the original question, you should not create new HTTP clients for each request. Client's maintain a connection pool and should be reused as much as possible.

You can fix that, and continue using your existing mock server by injecting the HTTP client.

Note also that the interface definition in the question doesn't match the implementation. These two method signatures are not the same:

```
HttpReq(params) ([]byte, error)  // Req
HttpReq(*params) ([]byte, error) // Impl
```

Pick one. I would probably go with the non-pointer type here. [And upper case initials are idiomatic in Go](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#initialisms) (`HTTPReq`, not `HttpReq`).

Add the client to the `Impl` type and use it in `HTTPReq`:

```
type Impl struct {
    client *http.Client
}

func (i *Impl) HTTPReq(p params) ([]byte, error) {
    req, err := http.NewRequest(p.method, p.url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    req.SetBasicAuth(p.cs, p.ci)

    res, err := i.client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()

    return ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
}
```

The Service type doesn't have to change.

In the tests, simply inject a test client into the `Impl` value:

```
import (
    "context"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"
)

func TestService_execute(t *testing.T) {
    var testHandler http.Handler // TODO

    srv := httptest.NewServer(testHandler)
    defer srv.Close()

    client := srv.Client()
    tp := client.Transport.(*http.Transport)

    // Direct all requests to the test server, no matter what the request URL is.
    tp.DialContext = func(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
        // Note that we ignore the network and addr parameters, since these are 
        // derived from the request URL and are unrelated to the test server.

        srvAddr := srv.Listener.Addr()
        return (&net.Dialer{}).DialContext(ctx, srvAddr.Network(), srvAddr.String())
    }

    svc := &Service{
        req: &Impl{
            client: client,
        },
    }

    svc.execute(/* ... */)

    // assert request, response, etc.
}
```

Comment: HI Peter 1+, thank you very much! I try your code and there is two missing part 1. `     `req: &Impl{
            client: client,
        },`this is not matching , I got error 2. is there sample example just in high level , (im clueless :) , how to test the `svc.execute(/* ... */)` ? again ,thank you very much for helpful assistance

Comment: The error is: `cannot use Impl literal (type *Impl) as type Req in field value:
 *Impl does not implement Req (wrong type for HttpReq method)
  have HttpReq(*params) ([]byte, error)
  want HttpReq(params) ([]byte, error)`

Comment: `params` != `*params`. Method signatures must match exactly to implement an interface.

Comment: HI again, I've adopted your example (see the updated question please) , in your example you use `impl` and add a `client` for it ,  but I've also the service struct`type Service struct {
    req Req
}`   hence it not working , clearly I miss something , can you please adjust your answer with `Req` interface and `Service` struct? this is what I miss to make it work, since currently with what I have (see the updated question) it doesnt work  :( , thanks a lot!

Comment: @NinaS, I added a paragraph about the method mismatch to the beginning of the question.

Comment: Ohh, I think im starting to get it , for me it takes some time to understand the concecpt :) , for you it's clear like the sun :) .  when debugging it it fail with in function `doSomthing` since it should return some `uuid` , I guess I need to  to create a `interface` for `doSomething` and add it to the `Service` struct , is it true ?   if yes, how should I mock it in the test ? just to return some number , can you provide sample for it ?  Thank you very much for helping me in this complex scenario

Comment: it would be great if you can add sample how would you mock function `doSometing`, in the test, this is the only thing Im missing here ...thanks.

Comment: That depends entirely on what `doSomething` does. You should ask a new question that includes the relevant details.

Comment: as you requested, I've opened new question, please see if you can help :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53924183/using-interface-for-testing-like-depency-injection

Answer (score 1):

Since Service struct already has an req interface, during tests initialise service object with mock that satisfies req interface.
Something like this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53805535/3968921

Comment: Ok , thanks, I saw this post already when searcing not sure I got it. what is ` type Implementation struct {
}` and how it's acatully should be tested what are the mock implementation in this case

Comment: it will be great if you can expand your example with explanation and mock test as it should be in real test , this is the things Im currently missing...